# Appendixpage showing a picture of all appendices

Tags: appendices

I want to make an Appendixpage which shows a simple minimal picture of all the appendices in the document. What I want is, that every time there is used `\chapter{}` after the `\appendix` command, there should be shown a picture of the appendix. Fx. if there is 5 appendices A, B, C, D and E on the Appendixpage there should be this: Perhaps with the title of the appendix if possible. I'm using report as the `\documentclass`.

[image]

Comment: Hihi, nice idea. But if you got 13 appendix chapters ... Does it really matter if there are four or five? It is an eye-catcher, not a real representation.

Comment: Perhaps not. But it could be nice anyway, I think.

Comment: @Simon: What is a the picture of the `Appendix`? Something like the playing cards above?

Comment: this can be helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36759/automatically-clipping-undrawn-objects-in-tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a fully automated solution...some scripting would be required for that, but this a start. The basic idea is to compile your document, save the resulting `pdf` as a separate file, then, using `tikz`, create nodes with the first pages of the appendices.

Best demonstrated by an example (following the above approach, the resulting `pdf` was saved as `file.pdf`; see `\pdfforappximgs`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%File path for pdf used to provide the images for the appendices. Must be a separate document from \jobname for access.
\def\pdfforappximgs{file}
%The rotation angle of the last appendix (drawn first)
\def\appxcardsinitialangle{40}
%The angle by which each successive appendix is rotated clockwise from the previous one
\def\appxcardsanglestep{15}
%Multiplier to get the x coordinate from the index
\def\appxcardxfactor{0.25}
%Multiplier to get the y coordinate from the index
\def\appxcardyfactor{0.25}
%The scale factor for the page
\def\appxcardscale{0.125}
%Numer of cards in a single row
\def\appxcardperrow{7}

\makeatletter
    % Array for appendices  
    \newcounter{appxpagecount}%
    \newcommand\setappxpage[2]{\csgdef{appxpage#1}{#2}}%
    \newcommand\addappxpage[1]{\stepcounter{appxpagecount}\setappxpage{\theappxpagecount}{#1}}%
    \newcommand\getappxpage[1]{\csuse{appxpage#1}}%

    %command to draw the appendix cards. Intened to be after \appendix.
    \def\appxcoverpage{%
        \chapter*{Appendices}%Add the heading to the cover page
        %Redefine \chapter and \chapter* to reference the page
        \let\old@chapter\@chapter%previous definition for the unstarred chapter
        \let\old@schapter\@schapter%\previous definition for the starred chapter
        \def\appendtochptexec{\protect\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\addappxpage{\thepage}}}%write to aux file the reference for the page 
        \gdef\@chapter[##1]##2{\old@chapter[##1]{##2}\appendtochptexec}
        \gdef\@schapter##1{\old@schapter{##1}\appendtochptexec}
        %Draw the cards
        \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\pdfforappximgs\relax\else
            \IfFileExists{\pdfforappximgs.pdf}{}{\gdef\pdfforappximgs{\relax}}%Check that the file exists
        \fi
        \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\pdfforappximgs\relax\wlog{No pdf file provided for appendix card display}\else%verify that the file is given and exists
            \pdfximage{\pdfforappximgs.pdf}%Get the number of pages in said pdf
            \edef\availpgs{\pdflastximagepages}
            \ifnum\theappxpagecount=0\wlog{No appendices for appendix card display}\else%do nothing if there are no appendices
                \expandafter\ifnum\getappxpage{\theappxpagecount}>\pdflastximagepages\wlog{Update the appendix pdf file...insufficient pages}\else%do nothing if there are not enough pages
                    %initialize the ranges      
                    \newcounter{cmini}
                    \newcounter{cmaxi}
                    \setcounter{cmini}{1}
                    \setcounter{cmaxi}{\appxcardperrow}
                    \ifnum\thecmaxi>\theappxpagecount\relax\setcounter{cmaxi}{\theappxpagecount}\else\fi
                    %upper limit for the loop must be 1 greater than the count to ensure all are included
                    \newcounter{cexclup}
                    \setcounter{cexclup}{\theappxpagecount}
                    \addtocounter{cexclup}{1}
                    \loop\ifnum\thecmini<\thecexclup
                        \begin{center}
                            \begin{tikzpicture}
                                \foreach \x in {\thecmaxi,...,\thecmini}{
                                    \pgfmathsetmacro\revx{\thecmaxi-\x+1};
                                    \node[fill=white,draw,anchor=south west,rotate=\appxcardsinitialangle-\appxcardsanglestep*(\revx-1)] at (\appxcardxfactor*\revx,\appxcardyfactor*\revx) {\includegraphics[page=\getappxpage{\x},scale=\appxcardscale]{\pdfforappximgs.pdf}};}
                            \end{tikzpicture}
                        \end{center}
                        %advance the counters to the next row
                        \setcounter{cmini}{\thecmaxi}
                        \addtocounter{cmini}{1}
                        \setcounter{cmaxi}{\appxcardperrow}
                        \addtocounter{cmaxi}{-1}
                        \addtocounter{cmaxi}{\thecmini}
                        \ifnum\thecmaxi>\theappxpagecount\relax\setcounter{cmaxi}{\theappxpagecount}\else\fi
                    \repeat
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text.
\chapter{Literature Review}
Some more text.
\chapter{Results and Discussion}
Even more text. 

\appendix
\appxcoverpage
\chapter*{Supplementary Material 1}
Some text.
\chapter[shorter title]{Supplementary Material 2}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 3}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 4}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 5}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 6}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 7}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 8}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 9}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 10}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 11}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 12}
Some text.
\chapter{Supplementary Material 13}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Some rough error checking is included in `\appxcoverpage` to ensure that the file name is provided (should be defaulted to `\relax`, there are appendices avaiable to draw, and that the referenced `pdf` is [long enough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198095/89497).

The above example yields the following on the appendix cover page:

[image: appx card array]

The `\appxcardperrow` command sets the maximum number of appendix cards shown in a group. As the number of appendices in a group increases, alternative effects are achieved:

[image: too many appx cards]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have inserted the above code, and it doesn't work for me. I have run the code. I had to uncomment the line " \appxcoverpage", otherwise it will not show anything. After that there are generated a pdf. and I rename it as "file.pdf" and runs the code again. It now displays alle the above, but not the picture with the appendices. Any idea what I does wrong ?

Comment: @Simon: I have updated the answer. Please try the revised code and let me know what you find.

Comment: Same problem as before. I have tried it a few times to be sure. Do you also have to uncomment the \appxcoverpage the first time to get something ?
It's very sad, because I like your solutions a lot.

Comment: @Simon: Try putting `\relax` in place of `file` in `\def\pdfforappximgs{file}`. That should let it run. If it completes, save the resulting `pdf` as `file.pdf` and replace `\relax` with `file`. I'll add a check to prevent this error.

Comment: I have done something, which apperently works. I'm not sure, what I has done, but I think, that I had to create just a random file and name it file.pdf the first time I runs it, and then delete this file and rename the created file as file.pdf. When I run the code agin. The above is shown.

Comment: @Simon: Great to hear! I have updated the code to include a check to see if the file exists, which should prevent the error you encountered.

Comment: Create. It works even better. I think my solution would be a little enoying with time. Thanks a lot for the help. Good day.

Comment: @Simon: It's hard to say this, but you should really consider to accept the answers to your questions -- so far you ask questions only, requesting help by others here but haven't neither upvoted nor accepted the answers. I know who upvoted this answer so far ;-)

Comment: Arh okay, thaks for the tip. I'm new at this forum, so I didn't knew. I try to remember next time :)

Comment: I have a problem with including the above code. The code can't handle this code, which produces page numbers of the appendices. 
\apptocmd\appendix{%
\clearpage 
\pretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}%
}{}{}
}{}{}

Is there a way to solve this problem. Perhaps with another code to produces the page numbers.